# How to remove the duplicate row based on the name in google sheet?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter, duplicates

[image]

HI everyone,

I want to remove the duplicate row based on the name column even though the Category is different, so the Category that I want to remove is Category 2 and the second, third,... row of category 1.

For example in the screenshot above, row 12, row 13 and row 14 are having the same name, so the row that should be removed is row 12 as it is Category 2 and also row 14 as it is he second row of category 1.

Is there any trick that I can use to achieve this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

### Edit

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A5:C), 9^9, 2, 2, 1)
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(SORT({A5:C, ROW(A5:A)}, 1, 1, 4, 1), 9^9, 2, 2, 1), 9^9, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks player0, I just updated my question, does this trick able to work on the new question?

Comment: I tested it works, but not sure I'm correct or not

Comment: it should hold. you can test it if you switch c13 and c14. if it throws undesired output we can still finetune it...

Comment: When I changed the value, seems like it doesn't work, I edited the question with a new screenshot

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VPmH22uSQDhzt60BXapmZ9NkvTWe8vKHtTk02QImQlk/edit#gid=0

Comment: @weizer answer updated

Comment: Thanks Player0, it is working now! Could you explain a bit on `SORT({A5:C, ROW(A5:A)}, 1, 1, 4, 1)` and also `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` ? I'm still not clear even though I split the formula out. Because I need to change and remove Category 1 instead of Category 2 when it is necessary

Comment: @weizer sure. given your A:C range we add extra column of row numbers via curly brackets { }. now that we have 4 columns we sort first column in ascending order and 4th column in ascending order. then we pass it to SORTN which will remove duplicates. next we use array_constrain to remove the 4th column and return all rows 9^9 with just first 3 columns

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you really need to sort on the row number, just don't sort on the last column:

```
=sortn(sort(A5:C,1,true),9^9,2,2,true)
```

[image]